# Using the argument passed to a python function as a string within the function

Tags: python

It's hard for me to describe what I'm trying to do for the title, but I feel like what I'm looking for is actually pretty simple.

So, I have a Python script that pulls data from a JSON config file and then executes a set of SQL queries.

The SQL queries are stored in the JSON file under `Queries.{name of query}.query`, like this: `Queries.List_of_Teams.query`, etc.

My main function iterates through the queries available in the JSON file like this:

```
    for i in conf.Queries:
        run_query(i)
```

and the function `run_query` looks like this:

```
def run_query(query_name):
    join_query = ' '.join(conf.Queries.query_name.query)
    CAT_query = join_query.format(CAT_start_date, CAT_end_date)
...
```

I'm struggling with the first line of the function. **How can I replace `query_name` in that first line with the actual query name passed to it from the for loop?** I've validated that `i` and `query_name` are both `List_of_Teams`, but I get this error when I run the script:

```
    join_query = ' '.join(conf.Queries.query_name.query)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'query_name'
```

Comment: `KeyError` instead of `AttributeError` suggests that it might be some exotic type where `conf.Queries[query_name]` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the power of `getattr`:

```
join_query = ' '.join(getattr(conf.Queries, query_name).query)
```